# Clefs for saxophone playing

Tags: saxophone, clefs

Is alto saxophone music written for ordinary treble and bass clefs?

Comment: If this question is just about clefs and not about the transposing of the Sax then it could have very easily just been answered with a google search.

Answer (score 5):

Most saxophones, and all the “usual” saxophones, are [transposing instruments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposing_instrument). This means that when they read and play a C on their sheets, the sound that comes out is not a piano C.

Saxophone music is thus always written in treble clef, but they don’t sound like a piano treble clef when played.

Sopraninos, **altos, baritones** and contrebass saxophones are in E♭, meaning that their C is a piano E♭.

Soprillos, **sopranos, tenors** and bass saxophones are in B♭.

There are also a few rare [saxophones in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_melody_saxophone) (i.e., non-transposing or, possibly, transposing by octaves) and in F<sup>1</sup>, but you probably can’t find music written from them readily in the commerce.

---

1. Adolphe Sax designed a range of saxophones for the symphonic orchestra, in which instruments are mainly in C, and another one for wind bands and military orchestra, in which instruments are usually in B♭ and E♭. Wind bands readily adopted the instruments while symphonic orchestra did not, which lead to the disappearance of C and F instruments.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. The question as I understand it asks about what clefs the instrument's music is written in. Bass / Treble / Alt or Tenor.

Comment: It’s written in the text that music is written in treble clef but that it does *not* correspond to the piano treble clef as in an middle A written for saxophone is not 442Hz (or so). What would you add to that?

Answer (score 2):

Saxophone is written in treble clef, transposed alternately in Bb and Eb (soprano is Bb, alto is Eb, tenor is Bb, etc.).